# Appling a density function to a sequence of a.s. converging UI random variables

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, uniform-integrability

A sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}$ in $[0,1]$ converges to a constant $c\in (0,1)$ almost surely. The sequence is also uniformly integrable.
Let $p$ be a probability density function on $[0,1]$, which is continuous and smooth in $(0,1)$. 
Then $p(X_n)\to p(c)$ a.s.

**Is it true that $\mathbb{E}[p(X_n)]\to p(c)$?**

If $p$ is bounded the result is trivial, however $p$ might explode at $0$ or $1$. 
It would be enough to show that the sequence $p(X_n)$ is uniformly integrable but I didn't manage to do that.
In particular I am interested in proving this result for a sequence of Beta random variables: 
$X_n=Beta(nx,n(1-x))$ which  converges almost surely to $x\in(0,1)$. 
It seems to me that this problem shouldn't be very hard to solve, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not. Take $$p(x) =C \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} 1_{(0,1)}(x)$$ for a normalizing constant $C>0$ such that $p$ is a probability density function. On $\Omega=(0,1)$ (with Lebesgue measure) consider $$X_n(\omega) := \begin{cases} \frac{1}{n^4}, & \omega \in (0,\frac{1}{n}), \\ \frac{1}{2}, & \omega \in [\frac{1}{n},1), \end{cases}$$ then $X_n \to \frac{1}{2}$ almost surely. On the other hand,

$$\mathbb{E}p(X_n) = C n^2 \frac{1}{n} + C \sqrt{2} \left(1-\frac{1}{n} \right)$$

and so

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}p(X_n) = \infty \neq C \sqrt{2} = p(\frac{1}{2})$$

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. What conditions on p would ensure that the result is true?  Requiring p to be bounded would work I think, but is there a weaker condition?

Comment: @Martina If you have some information on the growth of $p$ at $x=0$ and $x=1$ and also some estimates on the probability that $X_n$ takes values close to $x=0$ (resp. $x=1$), then it may be possible to prove convergence... but I don't see any reasonable general condition. By Fatou's lemma, we always have $$p(c)\leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}p(X_n),$$ but I don't know whether this is helpful for you.

Comment: In the case I am interested in, I don't have any additional information on $p$. But I could assume for example that $X_n \sim Beta(nc,n(1-c))$ , $c\in(0,1)$. In this case one  can also prove a central limit theorem for $X_n$:
$$
\sqrt{n}(X_n- c)\to \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma(c))
$$